# Element null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a radio button that I am masking as a button using an image background.  When the user clicks the li containing the radio button I package up the radio button as an object "el" and run a function to get results using the element as an argument.  This works fine in FF and Chrome but I get an error that the element is null or not an object.

Can anyone see my problem?

```
var selectedid = $this.find("[type='radio']").attr('id');
document.getElementById(selectedid).checked = true;
var el = document.getElementById(selectedid);
var el = $(el);
showResults( el );


function showResults( el ) {
    var id = el[0].dataset['item'];
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to declare el twice. $(document.getElementById(selectedid)); works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty inefficient and `.dataset` is not supported in all browsers.  Since you're already using jQuery, I'd suggest cleaning up your code like this:

```
var selected = $this.find("[type='radio']").first().prop("checked", true);
showResults( selected );


function showResults( el ) {
    var id = el.data("item");
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: jfriend yes I agree unfortunately.  I am always working on optimizing my code.  Thank you very much!  This worked well.  I believe besides the repeated statements dataset was my problem.  Thank you for pointing that out and helping me to optimize.